# Unir ajax de upload e input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formulário, file-upload

Tenho esse formulário:

```
<form id="formForum" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="boxContent">
            <div class="form" style="margin-top: 0">
                <div class="profile" style="background-image: url('painel/uploads/avatar_uploads/<?php echo $ver['avatar']; ?>')"></div>
                <div class="file">
                    <span class="file-name">Arraste sua imagem aqui (200x200)</span>
                    <div class="bt">Selecionar Imagem</div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="avatar" class="fake-file" />
            </div>
            <textarea class="form" placeholder="Altere a sua assinatura aqui" id="assinatura"><?php echo nl2br($ver['assinatura']); ?></textarea>
        </div>
</form>
```

Na qual estou enviando os dados através desse ajax:

```
$('#formForum').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var avatar = new FormData(this);
var assinatura = $("#assinatura").val();
if(avatar == undefined || avatar == '' || avatar == null){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/php/user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'assinatura': assinatura, 'comando': 'assinatura' },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#formForum').animate({'opacity':'0.6'}, 500);
        },
        success:function(result){
            $('#formForum').animate({'opacity': '1'});
            if(result == 'Assinatura alterada com sucesso!'){
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            }
            else{
                alert('Erro interno!');
            }
        }
    });     
}
else {
    if(avatar != undefined || avatar != '' || avatar != null){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/user.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: avatar,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#formForum').animate({'opacity':'0.6'}, 500);
            },
            success:function(result){
                $('#formForum').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 500);
                if(result == 'Avatar alterado com sucesso!'){
                    alert(result);
                    location.reload();
                }
                else if(result == 'A imagem é muito pesada!'){
                    alert(result);
                }
                else if(result == 'Extensão não aceita!'){
                alert(result);
                }
                else{
                    alert('Erro interno!');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/php/user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'assinatura': assinatura, 'comando': 'assinatura' },
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#formForum').animate({'opacity':'0.6'}, 500);
        },
        success:function(result){
            $('#formForum').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 500);
            if(result == 'Assinatura alterada com sucesso!'){
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            }
            else{
                alert('Erro interno!');
            }
        }
    });
    alert(avatar);
}
});
```

Estou enviando os dados por ajax diferentes porquê eu não consegui colocar todas informações em apenas um por quê está utilizando upload de arquivos...

(Estou utilizando dois ifs para que caso o usuário queira alterar apenas o avatar e não a assinatura ou vice e versa.)

Podem me ajudar em juntar esses ajax em um só?
Está aqui o php que utilizo:

```
else if($comando == 'assinatura'){
    // Usuário
    $username = $_SESSION['usuario_site'];

    // Variáveis
    $assinatura = isset($_POST['assinatura']) ? strip_tags($_POST['assinatura']) : '';

    // Querys
    $usuario = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='".$username."' AND status='true'");
        while($ver = $usuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $assinatura = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET assinatura='$assinatura' WHERE usuario='".$username."'");
            $assinatura->execute();
            if($assinatura){
                echo "Assinatura alterada com sucesso!";
            }else{
                echo "Erro interno!";
            }
        }
}
else{
    // Usuário
    $username = $_SESSION['usuario_site'];

    // Arquivo para onde o avatar será enviado
    $uploads = "../../painel/uploads/avatar_uploads/";

    // Formatos de imagem permitidos
    $permitidos = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".png", ".bmp");

    // Variáveis da imagem
    $nome = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tamanho = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    // Extensão do arquivo  
    $ext = strtolower(strrchr($nome,"."));

    // Verifica se a extensão está entre as extensões permitidas
    if(in_array($ext,$permitidos)){ 

    // Converte o tamanho da imagem
    $tamanho = round($tamanho / 1024);
        if($tamanho < 1024){ 
            // Verificando tamanho da imagem
            $nome_atual = md5(uniqid(time())).$ext;

            // Gera nome para imagem
            $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $img = getimagesize($tmp);

            // Envia imagem para banco de dados
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$uploads.$nome_atual)){
                $update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET avatar=:avatar WHERE usuario=:user");
                $update->bindValue(':avatar', $nome_atual);
                $update->bindValue(':user', $username);
                $update->execute();
                echo "Avatar alterado com sucesso!";
            }
            else{
                echo "Erro interno!";
            } 
        }
        else{ 
            echo "A imagem é muito pesada!"; 
        } 
    }
    else{ 
        echo "Extensão não aceita!"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Alguem poderia me ajudar em unir os ajax?

Comment: Você consegue fazer ajax de file upload com parâmetros como data, nome, usuário, senha, juntos, você usa servlet no back-end ?

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento do que seja servlet.

Comment: Desculpe esqueci o php... Servlets são classes Java, desenvolvidas de acordo com uma estrutura bem definida que quando instaladas e configuradas em um Servidor que implemente um Servlet Container, podem tratar requisições recebidas de clientes Web, como por exemplo os Browsers (Internet Explorer® e Mozilla Firefox®).

Comment: Eu não estou sabendo como enviar o parametro assinatura junto com o avatar do upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar se o seu input file tem arquivos você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
if(document.getElementById('avatar').files.length !== 0) {console.log('Existe arquivos');}
```

Espero ter ajudado!